# How to use VSCode to find which reports are using a specific field

Tags: soql, query, metadata-api, visualstudiocode, vs-code

I have used Eclipse in the past but unfortunately, Eclipse and Force.com IDE no longer work for me. I have switched over to VSCode along with the Salesforce DX and forcecode extensions (among many others) and this is the first time I have used this software. I was able to download all of the metadata from my salesforce instance. Now I need to perform a search to find all reports that use a specific field. Can anyone help walk me through the process to achieve this search? And once the search is completed, how do I replace a specific field used in a report with another field?

Comment: Wouldn't Find in Files/Replace in Files work here? Irrespective of VSCode, you can do a search/replace operation in any standard editor.

Comment: I'm still haven't used vscode but if you have the metadata use a notepad++ or text editor like sublime to find in all files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done by using the `Edit` menu and the options in VSCode. Just navigate to the folder and perform the operation there.

You can always perform such operation in any standard editor, viz., Notepad++.

[image]

[image]